# How to compress a directory into 7zip password encrypted archive?

Tags: python, compression, 7zip, password-encryption

I want to compress a directory recursively into a password encrypted 7zip archive in a platform-independent way.

I considered using these approaches, but none of them I found acceptable:

1. Calling 7zip executable directly using `subprocess` - This works great, but it's not platform-independent.
2. Using the `pylzma`/`py7zlib` modules - They work only on data already in memory, I can't imagine how to use them to compress directories.

Comment: I guess you don't want to walk the directory tree & read everything into memory to compress it. :) Another approach is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130634/compress-a-folder-recursively-as-7z-with-pylzma-and-py7zlib)

Comment: @PM2Ring No, concatenating files in memory is not my intention. I am simply looking for a script variant of Right Click on directory -> 7-Zip -> Add to archive. The link you posted does not discuss password protection or encryption, and the answer does not mention 7-Zip.

Comment: No, it's not exactly 7-Zip: the linked method creates an LZMA compressed tar archive, which should offer a similar compression ratio to a standard 7zip file. But of course it requires custom software to read & write. I'm not familiar with the various Python LZMA modules, but I see from a quick Googling that they don't offer password protection / encryption. Of course, adding such protection yourself's not too difficult, but once again, it's not going to be compatible with standard 7-Zip utilities. Oh well.

Comment: @PM2Ring, My primary concern is the strong security via AES-256 encryption that 7-Zip format offers (and it's cross-platformness). I can use other archive formats/modules for directory compression, but they don't offer encryption. So if you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: That's very kind, considering that I didn't actually answer your question.

Comment: @PM2Ring Uh, the answer is "It's not possible", which is a valid answer in my opinion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, it's not possible. But if these directories and folders are **only** going to be manipulated by software that you write, you can create your own "home-made" version of 7zip using the technique shown at [compress-a-folder-recursively-as-7z-with-pylzma-and-py7zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130634/compress-a-folder-recursively-as-7z-with-pylzma-and-py7zlib). This uses the `tarfile` module to gather the directory tree into a single file and then using the lzma / pyliblzma module to do the compression.

Unfortunately, the common Python LZMA modules do not offer password protection / encryption. But you can add your own, simply by encrypting the tarfile data before compressing it. See [Encrypt & Decrypt using PyCrypto AES 256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524994/encrypt-decrypt-using-pycrypto-aes-256) for details.

Comment: Alright, I ended up passing the path to 7z executable as an argument to my script.

Answer (score 3):

Now in Jun, 2020, it can be with py7zr v0.8.0 (https://pypi.org/project/py7zr/).

```
pip install py7zr


import py7zr
with py7zr.SevenZipFile('target.7z', 'w', password='secret') as arc:
    arc.writeall('.')
```

then you may observe a target.7z which is compatible with 7z command in Linux, mac and Windows.